# register manipulation avr microcontroller

Tags: c, avr

I'm just starting out. Have a little patience for my questions.
I came across a listing of a program where the following statement appears:

```
 DDRB &= ~((1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2));
```

My guess:
considering that at startup the microcontroller has by default the DDRB bits all set to 0, I get:

```
DDRB & = ~ ((1 << 0) | (1 << 0) | (1 << 0));    ===>>    DDRB & = ~ ((1) | (1) | (1));
```

which is different from the author's cooment. Where am I wrong?
2 # question: recital

```
volatile uint8_t portbhistory = 0xFF;
changedbits = PINB ^ portbhistory;
```

the second statement is not equal to:

```
changedbits = ~ PINB;
```

what changes? thanks to those who want to answer me.

Comment: `DDBx` are likely the bit indices and not the bit values.

Comment: thanks Eugenio Sh, that's what I wanted to know. Now everything is correct. Can you answer the second question as well? thank you

Answer (score 1):

No it is `DDRB & = ~ ((1 << 0) | (1 << 1) | (1 << 2));`

DDB0, DDB1, DDB2 are **bit numbers** defined in header file.

```
#define DDB0 0
#define DDB1 1 
/* ... actual values may be different */
```

Statement:

```
DDRB &= ~((1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2));
```

zeroes `DDB0`, `DDB1` & `DDB2` bits.

```
DDRB |= (1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2);
```

sets `DDB0`, `DDB1` & `DDB2` bits.

```
DDRB ^= (1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2);
```

toggles `DDB0`, `DDB1` & `DDB2` bits (sets their value to the opposite one).

Comment: Yes, the `(1 << DDB0) | (1 << DDB1) | (1 << DDB2)` is creating a **mask**.

Comment: >DDB0, DDB1, DDB2 are bit numbers defined in header file.

#define DDB0 0
#define DDB1 1 
/* ... actual values may be different */

thanks I was missing this piece. thanks